# c# Windows form application, wrong return type

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I'm trying to learn how to create Windows form applications in Visual studio. My first little mini project is to create a simple Numbers application, which gives the user two random numbers from 0-100, and adds these two together.

```
    private int button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rn1 = Random();                
        textBox1.Text = rn1.ToString();

        return rn1;
    }

    private int button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rn2 = Random();
        textBox2.Text = rn2.ToString();

        return rn2;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add the two numbers together
    }

    public int Random()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rn = r.Next(0, 100);
        return rn;
    }
```

Here is the code snippit i'm working on. "button1_click" and "button2_click" both adds a random number in a textbox in my application. The third button "button3_click" is where ill be adding the two numbers together like so:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number1 = button1_Click;
        int number2 = button2_Click;

        int sum = number1 + number2;
        textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

I want the first two methods to return the number that the Random() method creates, but I get the error "'int Form1.button_click(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type", and the same with button2.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: An event handler must signed with "void" (no return). Moreover, are you sure the Random function gives you no compilation errors?

Comment: I see. So I can't make the buttons give a return value. The Random function doesn't give me any errors. Do I need to create a method, that handles and returns the random number, and just have the button display the number?

Comment: The signature (ie parameter type and return type) of an event handler is defined by the code that raise the event (the winforms engine). You cannot change it at your will. The designers of WinForms decided that the button click event handler has void as return and an object and an event args as parameter. You should write the result of your Random function to a TextBox or a Label and read it back in the button3_click event handler

Comment: You could sore the numbers in the Buttons' Tag property. Your treatment of random is ok, although it is usually recommended to have only one random obejct at class level. but since the user clicks are long aport it will work.. In general a function will avoid uplicate code, though, so yes it is recommended but since the whole creation is not needed it is all about one line ..